# Is there is any option to split an order into two or more in prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, prestashop, addition

I wish to split an order into two or more, is there is any option to split the order in admin orders of Prestashop 1.6 or suggest if there is any addons in Prestashop.

Comment: Veeran, this is [Off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for SO, perhaps Quora is a better place. If you have tried something but got stuck, we can help you with that, take a look at our [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Comment: @dubes I don't think Presta people are all aware of Quora, and Presta forums are quite dead and messy.

Comment: @julien Im going develop a new feature to split an order so that i wish to know is there any option / add ons already exists in Prestashop.

Comment: Have you got any solutions?

Comment: @SyedIbrahim Prestashop has some options to split ordered products automatically like advanced stock management but i felt those are quite complicated.